# When compiling my solana code , I am getting "TypeError: Named argument "username" does not match function declaration."

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, polygon

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Ewitter{
    struct User{
        address wallet;
        string name;
        string username;
        string bio;
        string avatar;
    }

    mapping(address => string) public usernames;
    mapping(string => User) public users;

    function signup( string memory _username, string memory _name, string memory _bio, string memory _avatar) public{
        require(bytes(usernames[msg.sender]).length == 0, "User already exists");

        users[_username] = User({
            wallet: msg.sender,
            name: _name,
            username: _username,
            bio: _bio,
            avatar: _avatar
        });
        usernames[msg.sender] = _username;
    }
}
```

I am not getting why it's throwing "TypeError: Named argument "username" does not match function declaration" error despite of using same arguments as declared in User object.

[image]

Comment: It compiles without any problem for me.